# data transformation - multiple rows based on old row

Tags: r

I'm struggling to find the right function to use to transform my data in the following way, and was wondering if anyone could give me any suggestions. I'm not really sure about the right query to use for my search, so I apologize if this has a super obvious solution. This isn't quite a transformation from wide to long format, but it is somewhat similar... however, I wasn't able to find a solution using melt or transform.

```
$name  $total  $numcorrect
--------------------------
bob    2       2
bob    1       0
mary   4       3
...
```

becomes

```
$name  $n     $correct
-------------------------
bob    1     TRUE
bob    2     TRUE
bob    3     FALSE
mary   1     TRUE
mary   2     TRUE
mary   3     TRUE
mary   4     FALSE
```

In sort, for each $name, I want to transform the number correct out of the total into a binomial form. E.g. for the first row of Bob, I want 2 new rows that are TRUE, and for the second row of Bob, I want one row that is FALSE.

Comment: I don't understand why `bob 3` is `FALSE` since `total == numcorrect` for all of `bob`'s rows.  Could you be more specific about how you want to transform the first data frame into the second?

Comment: Whoops, super sorry Barker! I adjusted the main data frame to fix this. I will add more information into the question itself.

Comment: Ok, should we assume that it is always the last one that should be `FALSE`?  If `bob 1 0` was the first row rather than the second would the result still look the same?

Comment: No, they should happen in order. So if Bob 1 0 was the first row, then in the new data frame bob 1 FALSE would be the first row.

Comment: Could you please update your example to demonstrate how you want these things handled?   ex.  What would the result look like if you added a row to the top that was `bob 2 1`?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a column for total incorrect too and then use apply to repeat things in cbind.

```
df$inc=df$tot-df$cor
data.frame(do.call(rbind, apply(df, 1, function(x) cbind(name=rep(x[1],x[2]),n=1:x[2],correct=c(rep(TRUE,x[3]), rep(FALSE,x[4]))))))
  name n correct
1  bob 1    TRUE
2  bob 2    TRUE
3  bob 1   FALSE
4 mary 1    TRUE
5 mary 2    TRUE
6 mary 3    TRUE
7 mary 4   FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# try this
df <- data.frame(
    name = c('bob', 'bob', 'mary'),
    total = c(2, 1, 4),
    numcorrect = c(2, 0, 3),
    stringsAsFactors = F
)    

df.new <-  data.frame(
    name = rep(df$name, df$total),
    correct = rep(rep(c(T, F), nrow(df)), c(rbind(df$numcorrect, df$total - df$numcorrect))),
    stringsAsFactors = F
)
# > df.new
#   name correct
# 1  bob    TRUE
# 2  bob    TRUE
# 3  bob   FALSE
# 4 mary    TRUE
# 5 mary    TRUE
# 6 mary    TRUE
# 7 mary   FALSE

# if bob 1 0 was the first row:
df <- data.frame(
    name = c('bob', 'bob', 'mary'),
    total = c(1, 2, 4),
    numcorrect = c(0, 2, 3),
    stringsAsFactors = F
)

df.new <-  data.frame(
    name = rep(df$name, df$total),
    correct = rep(rep(c(T, F), nrow(df)), c(rbind(df$numcorrect, df$total - df$numcorrect))),
    stringsAsFactors = F
)
# > df.new
#   name correct
# 1  bob   FALSE
# 2  bob    TRUE
# 3  bob    TRUE
# 4 mary    TRUE
# 5 mary    TRUE
# 6 mary    TRUE
# 7 mary   FALSE
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Would you mind explaining to me how the correct = rep... row is working? I want to make sure I understand it.

Comment: @pomegranate, it basically repeat T, F by corresponding times of correct and not correct by row. I am quite busy now. May be you can figure it out by print the results of each step.